# Crystal Reports XI in VS2010 - trouble with POIDs and display information for multiple tables

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, report

I have 3 tables in my Crystal Report XI for VS2010 and here's the scene:

The 3 tables linked together with a POID.

- Table 1

  - Data: City, Date, Mill Name, POID (e.g. 1001)
  - Each POID has one record
- Table 2

  - Data: Shade Name (e.g. Blue), Quantity (e.g. 123), POID (e.g. 1001)
  - Each POID has one or more records
- Table 3

  - Data: Style Number (e.g. 123), Buyer's PO Number (e.g. 123), POID (e.g. 1001)
  - Each POID has one or more records

Table 2 and Table 3 are independent and only rely on Table 1 for their POID. The problem starts when there are differing number of records for a POID in Table 2 and Table 3.

Before Table 3 was added to the report, I grouped the report on the Table 1 POID and put the Table 2 record information in the Details section of the report. However, now that I have inserted the Table 3 records, the Table 2 and Table 3 records keep duplicating.

For example: for POID = 1001 there is one Table 1 record, three Table 2 records, and two Table 3 records. So, the outcome on the report is that each Table 2 record is repeated twice and each Table 3 record is repeated three times.

I don't want them to repeat themselves. I want them to display as they are on database.

I have used the POID group all of the table data using C#, VS2010, and SQLExpress2008.

I hope this is clear and that you can help. Thanks in advance.

Note: I did research a lot for this problem and then finally, asked here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I think you're misinterpreting how a query on such a database would look. It's actually giving you exactly what a database query would return in a view if you have your joins set up as something like `SELECT * FROM TABLE1 CROSS JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.POID = TABLE2.POID CROSS JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE2.POID = TABLE3.POID` which means: if there is one TABLE1 record, three TABLE2 records, and two Table3 records, you'd be selecting the TABLE1 record six times, each TABLE2 record two times for a total of six, and each TABLE3 record three times for a total of six. So, really, you're returning 6 lines but everything in the report is FUBAR because of how you have it laid out. Grouping on TABLE1 records is probably the only "correct" thing you did.

I think the easiest way to handle without this problem without creating additional database objects is subreports. Hopefully this will make sense and I can throw together an image if you want, but what you want to do is this:

1. In your main report, using your main database object as the data source, group on TABLE1 and add two additional sections within the group header or footer (your choice) and suppress the details section entirely.
2. In the first subsection you added to the grouping, add a subreport using only TABLE2 as the data source, use no groupings and put your TABLE2 information in the detail section. Add additional header and summary information to the report header and footer as you deem necessary.
3. In the second subsection you added to the grouping, add a subreport using only TABLE3 as the data source, use no groupings and put your TABLE3 information in the detail section. Add additional header and summary information to the report header and footer as you deem necessary.
4. Add any additional information to the footers that you want.

In essence it should look something like:

- Main Report - Report Header
- Main Report - Page Header
- Main Report - Group 1 Header

  - Group 1 Header - Section A - TABLE1 Record Information
  - Group 1 Header - Section B - SubReport 1

    - SubReport 1 - Report Header
    - SubReport 1 - Details - TABLE2 Record Information
    - SubReport 1 - Report Footer
  - Group 1 Header - Section C - SubReport 2

    - SubReport 2 - Report Header
    - SubReport 2 - Details - TABLE3 Record Information
    - SubReport 2 - Report Footer
- Main Report - Details (Suppressed)
- Main Report - Group 1 Footer
- Main Report - Report Footer
- Main Report - Page Footer

This will make a report with a TABLE1 header for each TABLE1 record followed by its TABLE2 and TABLE3 information without them repeating and making you crazy.

Does this make sense or help at all?

Comment: lol thanks, u are genious, i am trying this, the outlook is really helpful, thanks again :)

Comment: hey i want to group table 1,2,3 data with POID. By adding subreport, Subreport shows whole data..

Comment: JazakAllah,, i am done May Allah grant you the best success to @Ally .. all i did is make a report like Ally said and then linked the subreport POID field to Mainreport ID field ,, it makes up the day, Thanks Again